# RTL (Right-to-left) via auto layout broken on iOS 6.1 / iOS 7.0?

Tags: ios, autolayout, right-to-left

can it be that the RTL concept using auto layout is not working on iOS 6.1 and iOS 7.0 devices (also simulator) anymore? It is working for the iOS 6.0 (have only the simulator to check with) - so when setting the device language to Arabic, it mirrors the UI as expected for the 6.0 version.

(The Direction for the horizontal constraint is set to: "Leading to Trailing")

Have googled this issue for days, but without success...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Seems that iOS 6.1+ devices (simulator) require having the locale (ar) having defined  - adding it to the project will solve this problem.